# How can I Loop a column value if Row exists using INSERT ON KEY DUPLICATE UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

In this Table Scheme

```
[id  -  name  -  active]
[1   -  alex  -  0     ]
```

I have a `UNIQUE KEY` on `name, active`, What I'm trying to do is to `INSERT` a new Row

`[2   -  max  -   1     ]`

using `INSERT INTO table (name, active) VALUES (max, 1) ON KEY DUPLICATE active = 0`

That I want to loop at `active` **column** value,

If the `row:[2-max-1]` exists with `active=1` to change `active` value to `0`

And if exists with `active=0` to change it to `1`,

And if not exist to `INSERT` the row with `active=1`

I keep thinking but can't figure out a way to make this loop using only `INSERT . . . ON KEY DUPLICATE UPDATE`

Comment: it is easier if to make it 1,-1 if you can... and just do ON KEY DUPLICATE active = active * -1. it will toggle between 1 and -1 on each update.

Comment: You realize that you schema allows to have two rows, one with `('max',0)` and another with `('max',1)`. You don't mind that, right?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes, That the problem, I want it to keep swapping from `1` to `0` and from `0` to `1`, Not making a new row.

Comment: Then you need to change the UNIQUE constraint to `(name)` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple expression which returns what you want is `(NOT active)`.

So, your insert will become (you missed the `UPDATE` keyword):

```
INSERT INTO table 
    (name, active) 
VALUES 
    ('max', 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    active = NOT active ;
```

---

If you want to have only one row per `name`, then you need to change the `UNIQUE` constraint to `(name)` only. With that change, the above insert will do exactly what you want:

- Insert the row except if a row with that `name` already exists, in which case toggle the existing `active` value (essentially ignoring the `1 / 0` in the insert `VALUES`).